# Speed Time and distance question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A person walks from his house to school at 2.5 km/h and arrives 12 minutes late. When he comes back from school to home at a speed of 4km/h, he reaches 15 minutes early. What is the distance?
The answer is 3km

I have no idea how to solve this question. Can somebody please explain to me how to get the answer?

Comment: make the equations like- $\frac{x}{2.5}=t+\frac{12}{60}$ and $\frac{x}{4}=t-\frac{15}{60}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

distance = rate $\times$ time.

Assume distance = $D$, morning trip takes time $(T + 0.2)$ and afternoon trip takes
time $(T - 0.25).$

Morning rate was $R_1 = 2.5$ km/h and afternoon rate was $R_2 = 4$ km/h.

Then $D = R_1 \times (T + 0.2)$ and $D = R_2 \times (T - 0.25)$.

You have two (non-linear) equations in two unknowns, $D$ and $T$.

You can solve for these two variables.

Comment: I didn't understand why we took time 1 as T+0.2 an and time 2 as T-0.25. Where did 0.2 and -0.25 come from? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Curious Let $T$ be the time in hours that the trip is **supposed** to take.  Note that the distance to be computed is in kilometers, and the rate is in kilometers/hour.  Easiest is to express the morning and afternoon elapsed times in hours.  12 minutes **late** equates to 0.2 hours late, which equates to the morning trip taking $(T + 0.2)$ hours instead of $T$ hours.  15 minutes early equates to 0.25 hours early, which equates to the afternoon trip taking $(T - 0.25)$ hours instead of $T$ hours.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathtt{A\, "no\, Algebra"\, solution\,  for\, competitive\, exams}$

Difference in **minutes/km** in the two speeds $= \frac{60}{2.5} - \frac{60}{4} = 9$

Difference in times between two trips $=(12+15)=27\,$ minutes

Thus distance $= \frac{27}{9} = 3\, Km$

Comment: True, you didn't define any letter variables, but there is a lot of algebra hidden here.

Comment: That is true, that is why "No Algebra" was within quotation marks: but where time is at a premium, the "normal" Algebraic methods may consume too much time. I remember there was a chapter on "With or without Algebra" in perhaps "The Moscow Puzzles" or some such Russian publication

Comment: Can't understand the rationale of a downvote on an answer  with a method that could help strugglers in competitive examinations ! Glory to Al -Khwarizmi !